# Dynamically create numbered divs in Javascript + Jquery show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I would like to create numbered divs (such as eventbox1, eventbox2, etc.) in a loop and then have an option to show and hide them.

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
var html = '<div id="eventbox"+i></div>';
content.innerHTML +=  html;
}
```

I have also the following code in Jquery UI:

```
 function ShowHide(){
$("#eventbox"+1).animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 1000 });
}
 <div id="eventbox">
<a onclick="ShowHide(); return false;" href="" id="dialog_link">Show/Hide</a></div
```

I was wondering how to enable show/hide option of each div. I would like to have a show/hide link in each div and each time it is pressed, only this div hides/shows.

Comment: Can you give each eventbox a unique ID?  Something like "eventbox_1","eventbox_2", etc...

Comment: The question isn't completely clear.  Is there one <a> tag per <div> tag?  Or is there a single <a> tag that should show/hide every <div> tag, one at a time?  Or something else altogether?

Comment: I changed it, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: If you have the anchor tag inside the div, and the div is hidden, how would you open it up again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the element using jQuery and bind a handler to the anchor tag at the same time. If you put the anchor tag inside the div, there is no way to show the div once you've hidden it. So I'm attaching the anchor adjacent to the div. Not sure if this is what you want.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var $div = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("id", "eventbox" + i);
    var $a = jQuery("<a></a>").attr("id", "anchoreventbox" + i)
                              .html("Show/Hide")
                              .click(function() {
                var $a = jQuery(this);
                var eventboxID = $a.attr("id").replace(/anchor/, "");
                jQuery("#" + eventboxID).animate({"height" : "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
             });
    jQuery(body).append($div);
    $div.after($a);
}
```

or, instead of using the ID to find the div, you can also use `parent()`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var $div = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("id", "eventbox" + i);
    var $a = jQuery("<a></a>").attr("id", "anchoreventbox" + i)
                              .html("Show/Hide")
                              .click(function() {                    
                jQuery(this).parent().animate({"height" : "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
             });
    jQuery(body).append($div);
    $div.after($a);
}
```

**EDIT** so there's a problem here. You can't show the div once you hide it, since the link is inside the div. Perhaps you could put the link outside the div? Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't exactly what's desired...for example, there's no way that link could ever show anything, it's in the collapsed div.  The question still needs clearing up, because the final result doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That's a good point. Once the div is hidden, there's no way to open it up.

Comment: I changed my solution so that the anchor is inserted after the div.

Comment: In your last solution, `$a` is never inserted into the document, I think you wanted `.after()` there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following inital structure

```
<div id="eventbox" />
<div id="content">
    <!-- here come the eventbox+x div's -->
</div>
```

The following code does what you want I geuss

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = '';
    var links = '';
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        var event = 'eventbox'+i;
        html += '<div id="'+event+'">'+i+'</div>';
        links += '<a href="" id="a'+event+'">Show/Hide '+i+'</a>&nbsp;';
    }
    $("#content").html(html).find("div").hide();
    $("#eventbox").html(links);
    $("#eventbox a").click(function(eve) {
        eve.preventDefault();
        $("#content div:visible").hide();
        $("#"+this.id.substring(1)).animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 1000 });
        return false;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something compact like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
 $("<div></div>", {"id":"eventbox" + i}).append(
    $("<a></a>").text("Show/Hide").click(function() {
       $(this).closest("div").animate({"height" : "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
    })).appendTo($(content));
}
```

But the div isn't openable once closed...I think you want the anchor outside, then it'd be something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
 $("<div></div>", {"id":"eventbox" + i}).before(
   $("<a></a>").text("Show/Hide").click(function() {
      $(this).next("div").animate({"height" : "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
   })).appendTo($(content));
}
```

Another thought is that you don't need the ID on the div unless you have some outside reason, a class would be easier, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
 $("<div></div>", {"class":"event"}).before(
    $("<a></a>").text("Show/Hide").click(function() {
       $(this).next(".event").animate({"height" : "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
    })).appendTo($(content));
}
```